# If $f(x)=2px^2 + qx - p + 1\geq 0$ when $|x|\leq 1$ then what is the maximum value of $p+q$.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If I understand the problem correctly, then $f(x)$ is 'exactly' positive whenever $|x|\leq 1$.
Since this is a parabola (or quadratic equation) then there seems to be only one option. The x-intercepts are -1 and 1, and the parabola is downward facing.
The vertex is obtained for $f(0) = -p+1$, and $f(1)= 0$, $f(-1) = 0$.

Thus
$$f(1)= 2p+q -p +1 =0,$$
therefore $p+q=-1$.
$$f(-1) = 2p - q - p + 1= 0,$$ therefore, $p-q=-1$.

We have two simultaneous equations.

$$p+q = -1$$

$$p-q = -1.$$

Thus, $2p = -2$, hence $p = -1$, and $q = 0$.

But then the sum $p+q = -1$.

I believe the answer should be $2$. Is there something that I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the step where you said "there seems to be only one option" is a massive leap that is not justified. The condition that $2px^2+qx-p+1\ge 0$ when $|x|\le 1$ allows for *many* values of $p$ and $q$. After all, $p=q=0$ works just as well!

---

Let's write $f(x)$ as $f(x)=p(2x^2-1)+qx+1\ge 0$. Now, the idea is to find a suitable $x$ where the terms multiplying $p$ and $q$ will be *equal*, so that, with $2x^2-1=x=c$ for some value $c$ (hopefully in $[-1,1]$), you would have $c(p+q)+1\ge 0$, and this will produce a condition on $p+q$.

So, let's solve the quadratic equation $2x^2-1=x$, i.e. $2x^2-x-1=0$. The solutions are: $x=1$ or $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and both are in the range $[-1,1]$.

The solution $x=1$ is fruitless: it gives $c=1$ i.e. $p+q+1\ge 0$, i.e. $p+q\ge -1$, which is nice but is a *lower* bound for $p+q$.

With $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, however, the situation is diferent. It gives $c=-\frac{1}{2}$ and so $-\frac{1}{2}(p+q)+1\ge 0$, i.e. $-\frac{1}{2}(p+q)\ge -1$ i.e. $p+q\le 2$.

**Note** I could've cheated above and just said "set $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and this directly gives you $p+q\le 2$", but this won't really tell you where that value $-\frac{1}{2}$ is coming from.

---

The proof would be concluded if you can *find* an example of $p,q$ such that $p+q=2$. This is necessary because, so far, we have found an *upper bound* for $p+q$, but we have not found the *maximum* yet.

So let's set $q=2-p$ and see if we can find $p$ so that $f(x)$ satisfies the given conditions. The function now looks like this: $f(x)=p(2x^2-1)+(2-p)x+1=p(2x^2-x-1)+2x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)(2p(x-1)+2)$. This is a quadratic which has a zero at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, and it will stay non-negative if the other factor $2p(x-1)+2$ has a zero at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. So, $2p\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)+2=0$, which is true for $p=\frac{2}{3}$. This gives $q=2-p=\frac{4}{3}$.

**Note** Again I could've cheated and just said "try out $p=\frac{2}{3}, q=\frac{4}{3}$ but again this won't tell you where those values would be coming from.

Comment: Is it over interval [-1,1] or in the interval [-1,1] ?

Comment: @PLee I am sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: English expression "over interval [-x,x]" vs "in the interval [-x,x]". Sometimes I see "over interval".

Comment: this part is challenging. "Now, the idea is to find a suitable x where the terms multiplying p and q will be equal, so that, with 2x^2−1=x=c for some value c (hopefully in [−1,1]), you would have c(p+q)+1≥0" Why do p and q should be equal. How do we know that a large p and and a tiny q would not yield a larger sum?

Comment: Nobody said that $p$ and $q$ should be equal. The _coefficients_ multiplying $p$ and $q$ should be equal.  The idea is that, if for some $x$ you end up with the same number (I call it $c$) multiply both $p$ and $q$, then it can be pulled out of the bracket, giving you $c(p+q)+1\ge 0$, which you then use to make an inequality for $p+q$.

Comment: (And - you could see how it works: for $x=1$ you get $c=1$, and for $x=-1/2$ you get $c=-1/2$. In both cases you got some inequalities on $p+q$. In the first case it was a "wrong way" inequality, in the second case it was good.)

Comment: As for "over the interval" vs. "in the interval" - the meaning is really similar, though the first phrase hints that something is not just in the interval but also varies across the values in that interval, whereas the second phrase has just the meaning that it is in the interval but without implying that it will vary. At least that is how I understand it, I am not an expert.

Comment: Final question. How do we know that the idea $c(p+q)+1\geq 0$ generates the values where p and q are maximized? What happens if there is a combination of c+q that cannot be factored out by a common constant c, and that combination is the one which maximizes c+q ? @Stinking Bishop

Comment: I don't quite understand your last question. If $x=c=-\frac{1}{2}$, $|x|=\frac{1}{2}\le 1$, then we _know_ that $p+q\le 2$ as this is what $f(x)\ge 0$ turns into for this particular $x$. We don't know if $p+q$ can ever _reach_ $2$ (thereby the second part of the proof ("The proof would be concluded if...") but at least we are sure we've found an _upper bound_ $2$ of $p+q$. Put it like this: if $p+q>2$ then $f(-\frac{1}{2})<0$, which would be a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood the question. The answer is 2 if you take it to be asking for the maximum value of $p+q$, with $f(x)$ definitely non-negative when $|x|\le1$, but with unconstrained sign outside that region. I find $p+q$ is then maximised when $p>0$ and the minimum value of the quadratic is zero, giving $p=\frac{2}{3}$ and $q=\frac{4}{3}$. Do you want more detail or is this enough of a hint?

Comment: I needed more details but @Stinking Bishop provided them. Thank you both. I think I understood this only because of the more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is weird to ask what is the maximum value of $p + q$ if $(p,q)$ can only have one value. The title you wrote only says that $f(x) \geqslant 0$ when $|x| \leqslant 1$ but not that $f(x) < 0$ when $|x| > 1$.

First case : $p < 0$. In that case, we indeed have a downward facing parabola and $f(x) \geqslant 0$ on $[-1,1]$ if and only if $f(-1) \geqslant 0$ and $f(1) \geqslant 0$ i.e. $p + q \geqslant -1$ and $p - q \geqslant -1$ so $q \leqslant p - 1$ thus $p + q \leqslant 2p + 1 < 1$ since $p < 0$.

Second case : $p = 0$. In that case, $f(x) = qx + 1$ is affine, thus $f(x) \geqslant 0$ on $[-1,1]$ if and only if $q + 1 \geqslant 0$ and $-q + 1 \geqslant 0$, which means that $|q| \leqslant 1$. $p + q = q \leqslant 1$ and this value is attained when $q = 1$.

Third case : $p > 0$. In this last case, $f$ is facing up so you can check (draw it you will see it is quite obvious) that $f(x) \geqslant 0$ on $[-1,1]$ if and only if $f(-1) \geqslant 0$, $f(1) \geqslant 0$ (i.e. $p + q \geqslant -1$ and $p - q \geqslant -1$, which can be sumurised by $|q| \leqslant p + 1$) and one of the two following conditions is fullfilled,

$*$ The minimum of $f$ is non-negtaive i.e. the sign of $f$ doesn't change i.e. $\Delta = q^2 + 8p(p - 1) \leqslant 0$ i.e. $p \leqslant 1$ and $|q| \leqslant 2\sqrt{2p(1 - p)}$,

$*$ The minimum of $f$ is not in the interval $[-1,1]$. Since this minimum is attained at $x_0 = \frac{-q}{4p}$, it means that $|q| \geqslant 4p$.

Notice that all the conditions on $q$ are actually conditions on $|q|$ (which is normal because $[-1,1]$ is symmetric so you can always replace $x$ by $-x$, which changes $q$ into $-q$). Therefore, since we want to maximize $p + q$, we can choose $q \geqslant 0$ whithout loss of generality.

If we want the first condition to be checked, we must have $p \leqslant 1$, $q \leqslant p + 1$ and $q \leqslant 2\sqrt{2p(1 - p)}$. I let you verify that $q \leqslant 2\sqrt{2p(1 - p)} \Rightarrow q \leqslant q + 1$ and $p + q = p + 2\sqrt{2p(1 - p)}$ (in the best case) has for maximum $2$ (study the function $x \mapsto x + 2\sqrt{2x(1 - x)}$) and I let you find for which $(p,q)$ this maximum is reached.

If we want the second condition to be checked, we must have $4p \leqslant q \leqslant p + 1$, so $p \leqslant \frac{1}{3}$ and $q \leqslant p + 1$, thus $p + q$ reaches its maximum when $p = \frac{1}{3}$ and $q = \frac{4}{3}$ which implies $p + q = \frac{5}{3} < 2$.

You deduce that $\max\{p + q\} = 2$.